# Prove that $\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)-a^nf(ax)|d\mu=0$ for any $f\in L^1(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. For any $f\in L^1(\mu)$, prove that $$\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)-a^nf(ax)|d\mu=0.$$

---

My attempt:

Since 
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x)-a^nf(ax)|d\mu&=\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left((f(x)\chi_{f(x)\ge a^nf(ax)}-a^nf(ax)\chi_{f(x)\ge a^nf(ax)}\right. \\
&\quad \left.+a^nf(ax)\chi_{f(x)< a^nf(ax)}-f(x)\chi_{f(x)<a^nf(ax)})\right)d\mu\\
\end{align}
By change of variables $y=ax$, we have: 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}a^nf(ax)(\chi_{f(x)< a^nf(ax)}-\chi_{f(x)\ge a^nf(ax)})d\mu=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(y)(\chi_{f(\frac ya)< a^nf(y)}-\chi_{f(\frac{y}{a})\ge a^nf(y)})d\mu\\
\end{align}
Then by the dominated convergence theorem we can swap the limit and integral and we are done.

---

Is the proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: What is the dominating integrable function?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $|f(x)\chi|\le |f|\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and take $|f|$ as the dominating integrable function.

Comment: You don't have $|f(ax)| \leq |f(x)|$. you need a dominating function independent of $a$ to apply DCT.

Comment: But I have changed the variables and every integrand is of the form $f\chi_{\text{soomething}}$

Comment: What is the pointwise limit of the characteristic functions? can you say $I_{\{x: f(x) \geq a^{n}f(ax)\}} \to 1$ for almost all $x$ for any $L^{1}$ function $f$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right, there is a problem with the pointwise limit of a characteristic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: there exists a continuous function $g$ with compact support such that $\int |f-g| <\epsilon$. Write $g(x)-a^{n}g(ax)$ as $(1-a^{n})g(x)+a^{n}(g(x)-g(ax))$ and use Uniform continuity for $\int |g(x)-g(ax)|dx$.

Let me know if you want  a detailed proof.